# Where is my mistake in this SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology

```
"@PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> " +
            "SELECT ?o ?stringTest ?boolTest " +
            "where { "+
            "?s ?p ?o . "+
            "BIND (xsd:string(?o) as ?stringTest). " +
            "BIND (xsd:boolean(?o) as ?boolTest) "+
            
            "}\n ";
```

I am trying to execute this using Jena in Eclipse, but I can't find my mistake.
It is very simple query and I can not figure what my mistake is. Can anybody gice me some feedback?

Here is only SPARQL code:

```
@PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
            SELECT ?o ?stringTest ?boolTest
            where { 
            ?s ?p ?o . 
            BIND (xsd:string(?o) as ?stringTest). 
            BIND (xsd:boolean(?o) as ?boolTest) 
            
            }
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Encountered " <LANGTAG> "@prefix "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "\ufeff" ...
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "describe" ...
    "construct" ...
    "ask" ...
```

Comment: There shouldn't be an '@' at the beginning of Prefix, it is only PREFIX. This seems to be the only problem.

Comment: Yes, it is the only problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ is an optional prefix for "prefix" in the turtle RDF syntax...maybe that's where you got the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, the SPARQL processor encountered `@prefix` where it expected `prefix`.

SPARQL 1.1 syntax uses `PREFIX` (no `@` sign).

Turtle 1.1 syntax uses either `@PREFIX` (dating from before SPARQL) or `PREFIX` (now preferred, as it harmonizes with SPARQL 1.1).